# Create a column based of a status in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, status

can you help me please?

I have the following table in my dataframe:

| DATE | CUSTOMER | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | A | ACTIVATED |
| 02/01/2022 | A | ACTIVE |
| 03/01/2022 | A | INACTIVE |
| 04/01/2022 | A | EXCEPTION |
| 05/01/2022 | A | INACTIVATED |

I want to mark my dataframe row when my client inactivated (status inactivated). However, I only want to catch when the status at least once has been ACTIVATED. If my client's status is INACTIVATED, but it hasn't passed at least once as ACTIVED, it doesn't matter to me. And also I want to get just only when INACTIVATED is AFTER ACTIVATED.

Could you help me how I can do this in python? I'm having difficulties, here are 2 examples of result I would like to get.

1o option:

| DATE | CUSTOMER | STATUS | ACTIVATED/INACTIVATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | A | ACTIVATED | 1 |
| 02/01/2022 | A | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 03/01/2022 | A | INACTIVE | 1 |
| 04/01/2022 | A | EXCEPTION | 1 |
| 05/01/2022 | A | INACTIVATED | 1 |

2o option:

| DATE | CUSTOMER | STATUS | ACTIVATED/INACTIVATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | A | ACTIVATED |  |
| 02/01/2022 | A | ACTIVE |  |
| 03/01/2022 | A | INACTIVE |  |
| 04/01/2022 | A | EXCEPTION |  |
| 05/01/2022 | A | INACTIVATED | 1 |

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare `STATUS` per groups and test for values `s` - `1` if exist both, `0` if no:

```
s = {'ACTIVATED','INACTIVATED'}
df['ACTIVATED/INACTIVATED'] = (df.groupby('CUSTOMER')['STATUS']
                                 .transform(lambda x: set(x) >= s)
                                 .astype(int))
print (df)
         DATE CUSTOMER       STATUS  ACTIVATED/INACTIVATED
0  01/01/2022        A    ACTIVATED                      1
1  02/01/2022        A       ACTIVE                      1
2  03/01/2022        A     INACTIVE                      1
3  04/01/2022        A    EXCEPTION                      1
4  05/01/2022        A  INACTIVATED                      1
```

EDIT: For test dates with `ACTIVATED` if less like `INACTIVATED` create helper columns with aggregate `first/last`, compare datetimes in `eval` and last mapping `CUSTOMER` column:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], dayfirst=True)

s = (df.assign(ACTIVATED=df['DATE'].where(df['STATUS'].eq('ACTIVATED')),
               INACTIVATED=df['DATE'].where(df['STATUS'].eq('INACTIVATED')))
       .groupby('CUSTOMER').agg({'ACTIVATED':'first', 'INACTIVATED':'last'})
       .eval('ACTIVATED < INACTIVATED'))

df['ACTIVATED/INACTIVATED'] = df['CUSTOMER'].map(s).astype(int)
print (df)
        DATE CUSTOMER       STATUS  ACTIVATED/INACTIVATED
0 2022-01-01        A    ACTIVATED                      1
1 2022-01-02        A       ACTIVE                      1
2 2022-01-03        A     INACTIVE                      1
3 2022-01-04        A    EXCEPTION                      1
4 2022-01-05        A  INACTIVATED                      1
```

Comment: It's working, but I have one problem. I want just when INACTIVATED is after ACTIVATED (considering dates). I tested your solution, but I'm getting the rows when Activated is after inactivated and I don't want this kind of status. Could you help me how to get just when inactivated is after activated? thank you!

Comment: @haraujo - Can you test edited answer?

Comment: accepted as an answer! @jezrael